# c# how to unlock multiple text boxes

Tags: c#

I would like to unlock majority, but not all text boxes on the form. Currently I'm using this method that unlocks all text boxes:

```
    private void UnlockVnos(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = false;
                ((TextBox)c).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is: how can I exclude particular text boxes that I don't want to be unlocked (I have to loop through some 50 text boxes and unlock all of them, except some 10 of them that have to stay locked. The first thing that came to my mind is to set the text boxes 'Tag' property, but somehow I can't make it work in my method. Any help appreciated.

Comment: WPF or winforms?

Comment: Show me how you tried the Tag property, I'm sure we can make it work

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Winforms

Comment: `if((TextBox)c).Tag == "myTag")` ???

Comment: Do they have the same parent container? So you could go only through the controls which are in this container. Another way could be if you have a name convention, where you can check if this is a wanted box. One more way could be to use the tag field of the TextBox. Set this to a value (e.g. to true) and check if the iterated TextBox has this value.

Comment: @EpicKip I tried: `if(((TextBox)c).Tag = 1);`, but I get a casting error: `
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Tag property accepts only string values. 1 is integer. @Flin

Comment: @Berkay Plus it should be `==`

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect so swift and so many replies. Thank you all. I'm sure now I can solve this.

Comment: @Flin - Do you need to keep same tag for all the texboxes you dont want to unlock? If yes, go for my answer. Its simple pretty and clean!

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Please see comment below your solution.

Comment: @Flin - Saw ur comment and updated my answer accordingly..u can use that solution now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I set the textbox tags of the boxes I did not want to unlock to "DoNotUnlock".

```
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox && (string)c.Tag != "DoNotUnlock")
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = false;
                ((TextBox)c).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
            }
        }
```

With a dictionary of keys. I'm going for a Dictionary for more versatility, where the Bool could be used in combination with the key. A code sample will be added for that shortly.

```
    private void UnlockVnos()
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> mytags = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        mytags.Add("DoNotUnlock", false);
        mytags.Add("StayAwayFromThisBox", false);
        mytags.Add("DontEvenDateUnlockThis", false);

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if ((c is TextBox && c.Tag == null || !mytags.Keys.Contains((string)c.Tag)))
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = false;
                ((TextBox)c).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
            }
        }
    }
```

3rd sample using the bool in the dictionary

```
    private void UnlockVnosAgains()
    {
        //here we have a Dictionary of all the tags you want to handle.
        //True for boxes which should be readonly, false for boxes which should not be.
        Dictionary<string, bool> mytags = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        mytags.Add("SomeTag1", false);//leave it alone
        mytags.Add("SomeTag2", true);//make it readonly
        mytags.Add("SomeTag3", true);//make it readonly
        mytags.Add("SomeTag4", false);//leave it alone
        mytags.Add("DoNotUnlock", true);//make it readonly

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            //if C is a textbox, and the Tag is NOT null and the dictionary contains the tag
            if ((c is TextBox && c.Tag != null && mytags.Keys.Contains((string)c.Tag)))
            {
                ((TextBox)c).ReadOnly = mytags[(string)c.Tag];//assign the appropriate bool from the dictionary
                ((TextBox)c).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);//do your color thing... wink wink, this one could be stored along with your true or false too
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if there are multiple Tag values?

Comment: @Berkay something like this: I'd have the tag values listed in a dictionary, and compare against it. `&& !Dictionary.ContainsKey((string)c.Tag)`

Comment: I know the way, but your solution doesn't include it :)

Comment: It's not in the op, but I can sure add that.

Comment: @blaze_125 Thanks, your answer was very helpful.

Comment: @Flin , Anytime! Please accept as the answer if you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have same tag value for all of the textboxes you dont want to unlock.

Try following:

```
private void UnlockVnos(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            var tBox = (TextBox)c;
            var tag = Convert.ToString(tBox.Tag);

            if (tag !="YourTagValue")){ //Take care of case-sensitivity
               tBox.ReadOnly = false;
               tBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple Tag values?

Comment: Why he needs to keep different values for the textboxes he doesnt want to unlock?

Comment: Thats why I said "if" :)

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Thanks Muhammad. Although I like your solution as it's short and sweet, I'm getting an error at `if (!tBox.Tag.Equals("YourTagValue"))` line. Error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Flin - I've updated my answer n fixed the problem. This solution is faster, clean and simple..try this n mark it as answer if it helps u :)

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Thanks Muhammad. It's working now, but now I get a warning `CS0252 Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'`. I tried: `if (tBox.Tag.ToString() != "YourTagValue")`, but in this case I get the same error as before: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @MuhammadQasim I should use `if ((string) tBox.Tag != "YourTagValue")` instead of `if (tBox.Tag.ToString() != "YourTagValue")`. I found that in blaze_125 answer. It works as it should now.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Thanks, Yes, this also works, Is it better to use 'Convert.ToString' vs '(string)' and why?

Comment: @Flin - Convert.ToString is safe..it will set empty string if Tag is null. The discussion is too long now. Please avoid more comments :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void UnlockVnos(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            var textbox = (TextBox)c;

            textbox.ReadOnly = textbox.Tag == "myTag";
            textbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192);
        }
    }
}
```